# Kotlin Adapter Declaration issue: Type mismatch: inferred type is MyTabAdapter but RecyclerView.Adapter<(raw) RecyclerView.ViewHolder!>? was expected

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

Making tabs with TabLayout and ViewPager2 and fragment.
I am getting type mismatch on adapter. I am new to KOTLIN and Android
if any suitable tutorial link is there which has implementation of tablayout with viewpager2

```
class ProfileActivity:AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
lateinit var viewpager2: ViewPager2

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)

    // Toolbar

    toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.apply {
        title="Profile"

        // show back button on toolbar
        // on back button press, it will navigate to parent activity
        // mentioned in AndroidManifest.xml
        setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
    }

    // Tab layout - add tab items
    tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.profileTabLayout)
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Personal"))
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Education"))
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Interests"))
    tabLayout.tabGravity=TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL

    //Viewpager2
    viewpager2=findViewById(R.id.profileViewPager)

    //Adapter for view pager
    val adapter1=MyTabAdapter(this,supportFragmentManager,tabLayout.tabCount)

    viewpager2.adapter= adapter1

    viewpager2.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(
        object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            viewpager2.currentItem = tab.position
        }
        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

        }
        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

        }
    }
    )
}
```

}

**Here is Code of MyAdapter
Probably i am confused with FragmentStatePagerAdapter as it shows deprecated if there is any easy method to implement then i can try that also.**

```
class MyTabAdapter(profileActivity: ProfileActivity, supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager, private var tabCount: Int) {


fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {

    when (position) {
        0 -> {
           // val homeFragment: HomeFragment = HomeFragment()
           // val personalFragment:PersonalFragment=PersonalFragment()
            return PersonalFragment()
        }
        1 -> {
            return EducationFragment()
        }
        2 -> {
            // val movieFragment = MovieFragment()
            return InterestsFragment()
        }
        else -> return null
    }

}
fun getCount(): Int {
    return tabCount
}
```

}

```
**Here is one of the fragment . I have three fragment in total.** I 

class PersonalFragment : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal, container, false)
}
```

}

```
 I have referred the https://www.javatpoint.com/kotlin-android-tablayout-with-viewpager for implementation
```

I

Comment: Please attach the source code of `MyTabAdapter`

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that I can see:

1. The article you were following used `ViewPager` but the snippet of codes that you attached showed that you were using `ViewPager2`.
2. `MyTabAdapter` extends nothing, it has to extend some kind of base adapter.

In your case, I suppose you wanted to use `ViewPager2` to page through some fragments. You need to use [`FragmentStateAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter).

Modify `MyTabAdapter` to be liked this

```
class MyTabAdapter(profileActivity: ProfileActivity, private val tabCount: Int) : FragmentStateAdapter(profileActivity) {

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment? {

        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                // val homeFragment: HomeFragment = HomeFragment()
                // val personalFragment:PersonalFragment=PersonalFragment()
                return PersonalFragment()
            }
            1 -> {
                return EducationFragment()
            }
            2 -> {
                // val movieFragment = MovieFragment()
                return InterestsFragment()
            }
            else -> return null
        }

    }
    
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return tabCount
    }
}
```

Check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration) for detailed document of migrating from `ViewPager` to `ViewPager2`